# How can I write data about process assignees to database

Tags: camunda

I use camunda 7.2.0 and i'm not very experienced with it. I'm trying to write data about users, who had done something with process instance to database (i'm using rest services) to get some kind of reports later. The problem is that i don't know how to trigger my rest(that sends information to datebase about current user and assignee) when user assignes task to somebody else or claims task to himself. I see that camunda engine sends request like

```
link: engine/engine/default/task/5f965ab7-e74b-11e4-a710-0050568b5c8a/assignee
post: {"userId":"Tom"}
```

As partial solution I can think about creating a global variable "currentUser" and on form load check if user is different from current, and if he is - run the rest and change variable. But this solution don't looks correct to me. So is there any better way to do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [task listener](http://docs.camunda.org/7.2/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-delegation-code-task-listener) which updates your data when the assignee of a task is changed. If you want this behavior for every task you could define a [global task listener](http://docs.camunda.org/7.2/guides/user-guide/#process-applications-process-application-event-listeners).